# Issues with using implode after pushing the variables into the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently testing how to use a simple implode for a mysql query after I have pushed the variables into the array. I just can't get around the error, I know it says, invalid arguments, but the array has been set up and I know it worked in another part of my page with an almost identical code.. I guess there are somewhere missing some ' or " or . or but no matter what I change it doesn't work.

I appreciate any help!

Here is the part where I set up the array:

```
$LFBsubjects = Array();
$LFBsubjects[] = $dataset2['subject1'];
$LFBsubjects[] = $dataset2['subject2'];
```

And the output I have printed via print_r is:

```
Array ( [0] => Mathematics [1] => English )
```

Now comes the query, which uses the implode function:

```
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "
SELECT subject_id FROM subjects
WHERE subject IN (".implode(',', $LFBSubjects).")";

$statement = $pdo->query($SelectTSubjectsQuery);
```

The error is:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/xxx/html/lfb.php on line 626
```

Comment: This is quotes issue chk my answer

Comment: Chk my update u r using wrong variable name

Comment: No need to use hard code value yur variable name is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid argument error means you need to use quotes between string for MYSQL QUERY like `IN ("test")`
You can use as like:

```
$values = implode("','", $LFBsubjects);    
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "    SELECT subject_id FROM subjects    WHERE subject IN ('".$values."')";
```

**Explanation:**

Your array consists on string values when you use IN RANGE in MYSQL for string values than you must need to pass it in quotes.

**Basic example:**

```
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "
SELECT subject_id FROM subjects
WHERE subject IN ('val1','val2')";
```

**Update 1**

After checking your comments, you are using wrong variable name in implode

```
$LFBSubjects
```

This should be this:

```
$LFBsubjects // with small s
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I have now tried it as you described it and got another: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/xxx/html/lfb.php on line 624` for this line: `$impsubjects = implode("','", $LFBSubjects);` with the same `print_r ($LFBsubjects);` which outputs: `Array ( [0] => Mathematics [1] => English ) `

Comment: @franky2207   try with hard code values $SelectTSubjectsQuery = "
SELECT subject_id FROM subjects
WHERE subject IN ('English','Mathematics')";

Comment: U can also chk yur query echo yur query u will get the idea

Comment: Oh maaaaan... it's really the small "s" which I have written as a capital letter.. and I tried for at least an hour with different ' and . and then it's just this.. Thank you very much Sir, really appreciate your help!!:)

Comment: @franky2207 chk my update u r using wrong variable name

Comment: yep got it, THANK YOU! Take all my cookies!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100701/discussion-between-devpro-and-franky2207).